# How to Handle the checkbox ischecked and unchecked event in android

Tags: android, checkbox

i am new in android.i make a simple maths apps.
i use the check box for select right option but  problem  is here the answer option is not only one but also two,three means multi select so i use the check box

```
chkOption.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

event and try to handle this.and store the select value in one Arraylist.but when i select option the value is add in arrayList but when i do uncheck(Diselect) then also the event is occur and the value add in arraylist.
my code is below

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {   
        CheckBox chk=(CheckBox) buttonView;
        if(chk.isChecked())
        {
            forMetchCheckBox.add(String.valueOf(chk.getText()));            
        }
    }
```

forMetchCheckbow is my String ArrayList .So i can what to do?
How to Handle this problem.
if any user deselect the option then the checkbox select value is remove from ArrayList.it`s possible?

Comment: How many checkboxes you have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are having more than one checkbox and you are setting global listener for every checkbox. So, in that case you need to identify the event for specific checkbox also.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {   
        int id = buttonView.getId();
        if(id == R.id.chk)
        {
          if(chk.isChecked()){
               forMetchCheckBox.add(String.valueOf(chk.getText()));
            }
           else{
               forMetchCheckBox.remove(String.valueOf(chk.getText()));
           }
        }
        else if(id == R.id.chk1){
           ....
        }
    }
```

and so on, that will make your listener work perfect.

Comment: yes i also use this code but my problem is how to remove the add item in arraylist after the select  checkbox deselect(unchecked)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is your if condition. It should be:

```
if( isChecked )
```

and not

```
if( chk.isChecked() )
```

Comment: i edit my answer..isChecked is the function parameter. I made a writing mistake.

Comment: but how to remove the add item after deselect(un checked) the scheck box.

Answer (score 1):

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                      if(isChecked){
                          chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
                            checkbox_timeslot.add(chetimeslot);

                        }
                       else{
                           chetimeslot = (String)chk.getTag();
                            checkbox_timeslot.remove(chetimeslot);


                       }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**To Select Maximum 5 Checkbox at one Time or Count selected and unselected checkbox in Custom listview with CheckBox**

```
     package com.test;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class ListViewCheckboxesActivity extends ListActivity {

    AlertDialog alertdialog = null;
    int i1, i2, i3 = 0;
    Country rowcheck;
    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    ListView listView = null;
    int k = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fmain);

        // Generate list View from ArrayList
        displayListView();
        checkButtonClick();

    }

    private void displayListView() {

        // Array list of countries Equipments
        ArrayList<Country> rowcheckList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        Country rowcheck = new Country("", "Hex Bolts", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Hex Cap Screw", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Round Head Bolt", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Slotted Head Hex Bolt", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Socket Cap Screw", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Sockets", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Square Head Bolt", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Carriage Bolt", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);
        rowcheck = new Country("", "Plow Bolt", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);

        rowcheck = new Country("", "Struts Clamp", false);
        rowcheckList.add(rowcheck);

        listView = getListView();

        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.rowcheck_info,
                rowcheckList);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Country rowcheck = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }

        });

    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {
        private ArrayList<Country> rowcheckList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Country> rowcheckList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, rowcheckList);
            this.rowcheckList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            this.rowcheckList.addAll(rowcheckList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView code;
            CheckBox name;
        }

        @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

   if (convertView == null) 
   {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.rowcheck_info, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
   holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
     public void onClick(View v) 
     { 
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 
      Country rowcheck = (Country) cb.getTag(); 

      //To check maximum 5 Selection
      if(k>5)
      {

          if(!cb.isChecked())
          {


                  rowcheck.selected=true;
                  System.out.println(k--);


           }

          else
          {
              System.out.println("if block in-----");
              cb.setChecked(false);
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maximum Selection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }


      }

      else
      {

          System.out.println("else block in-----");

          if(!cb.isChecked())
          {


                  rowcheck.selected=true;
                  System.out.println(k--);

           }


          else if(cb.isChecked())
          {


                     rowcheck.selected=false;
                     System.out.println(k++);



          }

      }





     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
       " is " + cb.isChecked(),
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       rowcheck.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
     } 
    }); 
   }
   else 
   {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Country rowcheck = rowcheckList.get(position);
  // holder.code.setText(" (" +  rowcheck.getCode() + ")");
   holder.code.setText(rowcheck.getName());
  // holder.name.setText(rowcheck.getName());
   holder.name.setChecked(rowcheck.isSelected());
   holder.name.setTag(rowcheck);

   return convertView;

  }
    }

    private void checkButtonClick() {

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

                ArrayList<Country> rowcheckList = dataAdapter.rowcheckList;

                System.out.println("Size" + rowcheckList.size());
                int j = 0;
                ArrayList<String> stt = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < rowcheckList.size(); i++) {
                    Country rowcheck = rowcheckList.get(i);
                    // System.out.println(rowcheck.getName());

                    if (rowcheck.isSelected()) {
                        stt.add(rowcheck.getName());
                        // Country.st=new ArrayList<String>();
                        String s = rowcheck.getName();
                        System.out.println("String--" + rowcheck.getName());
                        Country.st.add(s);
                        j = j++;
                        System.out.println(j++);

                        responseText.append("\n" + rowcheck.getName());

                    }

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < stt.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Names----" + stt.get(i).toString());
                }

                if (j >= 1 && j <= 5) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this,
                            PickedItemListView.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this,
                            "Maximum 5 Selection Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

                Toast.makeText(ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this, responseText,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
//Logout ALert Box
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                    .from(ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this);
            View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.logout_popup, null);
            final Button ok = (Button) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            final Button cancel = (Button) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    (ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this));
            dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
            dialogbuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            alertdialog = dialogbuilder.create();
            alertdialog.show();

            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View paramView) {
                    alertdialog.dismiss();
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(
                            ListViewCheckboxesActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            });

            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View paramView) {
                    alertdialog.cancel();
                }
            });

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBox_sound.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            var boolSoundOn = (isChecked) ? true : false;

        }
    });
```

It works Perfect...